# Gparted not allowing me to partition sda3

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Installed GParted on my day old Ubuntu desktop. Ubuntu was installed in UEFI mode. I want to dual boot win10 so I decided to install GParted to make a partition.

Here's what my GParted screen looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smX6Q.png)

It should be noted that there were no mounted files to begin with. This was the same screen I saw at the very beginning.

When I right clicked on the sda3 partition (the one I wanted to make a partition from), it wouldn't allow me to resize the partition (no error message came up, the "resize" button was just unfilled and nothing happened when I pressed it).

What should I do to make a partition?

Comment: /dev/sda4 is allready a partition. What do you want to do with it ?

Comment: It doesn't show up for me, how do I make it viisble?

Comment: With UEFI, you have to also install Windows in UEFI mode if drive is gpt. And if UEFI it should be gpt partitioned. Windows also in UEFI mode wants lots of partitions, so just create unallocated space with the LVM tools as posted in answer.https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions?view=windows-11#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot /dev/sda3 is an encrypted partition.
GParted cannot resize encrypted partitions on its own.
See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions for instructions how to do it.

Comment: Is there something like Gparted that would recognize the encrypted partition's true size, despite it being an lvm partition?

Comment: Not that I know of.